# How do I multiply values within id and display answer?

Tags: html, jquery

How do multiply each value in the div with class="crtTotal" and have a div output that displays the answer: for example 1.75 x 3.65 x 2.10 = 13.41

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>



    <div id="box" class="boxlit">
        <div class="box" data-id="75">Weston Bears - Cooks Hill United
            <br>Home
            <div class="crtTotal">1.75</div>
        </div>
    

    <div class="box" data-id="79">Logan Lightning - Brisbane City
        <br>Draw
        <div class="crtTotal">3.65</div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="box" data-id="81">Eastern Suburbs Brisbane - Moreton Bay United Jets
        <br>Home
        <div class="crtTotal">2.10</div>
    </div>


    <br>

    <div class="total">Total</div>
```

Here Is the script I Came up with but works on sum (Addition), how do I Get It To Multiply for example 1.75 x 3.65 x 2.10 = 13.41

```
<script>

$(function() {


var sum = 0;
$('.crtTotal').each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat(this.innerHTML, 10)
})

$('.total').text(sum);

})

</script>
```

Comment: Firstly you need to remove the duplicate `id` attributes as they have to be unique. Change them to classes instead. Secondly, show us the code you've written to attempt this yourself, so we can help you debug it. SO isn't here to write code for you

Comment: I am trying to find a script online for multiplying on class values but only getting for sum functions, Can you please edit for me a script to multiply them, i have edit the id to class in the code as you requested

Comment: Good Day Rory, I've seem to find the script for sum, how can I edit it to multiply and give answer to 2 decimal places

Comment: To multiply change `+=` to `*=`. To round to 2dp use `.text(sum.toFixed(2));`

Comment: when I use *= the answer remains 0, its not changing

Comment: That's because `sum` is initialised to zero. I've added an answer for you with a different approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you initialise `sum` to zero. Therefore every number you multiply by `sum` is still zero. To fix this you could create an array of all values then use `reduce()` to multiply them all together.

To display the output to 2DP you can use `toFixed(2)` - but be aware this will convert the value to a string. Only call this function when presenting the value in the UI, not when it will be used for further calculation.

```js
let values = $('.crtTotal').map((i, el) => parseFloat(el.textContent)).get();
let total = values.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
$('.total').text(total.toFixed(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" class="boxlit">
  <div class="box" data-id="75">Weston Bears - Cooks Hill United
    <br>Home
    <div class="crtTotal">1.75</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" data-id="79">Logan Lightning - Brisbane City
    <br>Draw
    <div class="crtTotal">3.65</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" data-id="81">Eastern Suburbs Brisbane - Moreton Bay United Jets
    <br>Home
    <div class="crtTotal">2.10</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="total">Total</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good Day, If I may ask, whenever I remove one class, it doesn't re-calculate the total, but when i add another class it keeps adding, how do I make it to calculate total every time I remove or add?

Comment: That depends on your logic, and how you're amending the classes. I'd suggest starting a new question about it

Comment: Good Day, I figured it out by using Event Listener, the only problem is now when everything is removed the null value doesn't show, How can I Be able to make it show null value as 0 instead of not showing anything?